# best way to target the parent div - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

```
<div id='a_div'>
    <ul>
        <li><button type='button' onclick='a_function()'>Button</button>
    </ul>
</div>
```

in the example set up above, what would be the best way to pass the div's id into a_function
is there a better way than doing `onclick='a_function(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id)'`

Comment: In plain JavaScript, that method is just fine.

Comment: just pas $('#a_button') if you are using jQuery. Or pass the div name and use document.getElementById in the a_function.

Comment: @Asdfg I think the point is that the id is not known ahead of time so the parent must be located.

Comment: If he doesnt know where the parent is, how does he know it is 3 level up?

Comment: yes, the concept here is that there would be many of the same div output onto the page, each would have a unique id to it automatically set, and based on in which div the button is clicked i'd like its parent div's id

Comment: well, in that case this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id is good enough

Comment: For what do you need that id in the script? And why can't you automatically set an argument to the handler function, when you can set ids?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using JQuery then [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) can solve your problem.

Comment: sorry i should have tagge jQuery, i actually used .closest to solve this....
onclick='thisFunction(this)'

function thisFunction(element){
var div = $(element).closest('div');
var id = div[0].id;
alert(id);
}

Comment: This is available in vanilla JS as of ~2015. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take it out of the inline handler, you could just pass `this`, then traverse in the method...

```
onclick='a_function(this)'
```

```
function a_function(el) {
    var id = el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/CUyZ4/

---

Or if you don't like to repeat `parentNode`, make a function...

```
function up(el, n) {
    while(n-- && (el = el.parentNode)) ;
    return el;
}
```

```
function a_function(el) {
    var id = up(el, 3).id;
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/CUyZ4/1/

---

Or use it directly inline...

```
onclick='a_function(up(this, 3).id)'
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/CUyZ4/2/

Answer (score 0):

The best way now that the OP says jQuery is acceptable, is to use the `parents` function

```
function a_function(){
    var self = $(this), 
        parentDiv = self.parents('div');
}
```

This will get you the first `div` it encounters while traversing up the DOM chain. Ofcourse, if you want it to be a bit more specific, you can specify a particular class for all those divs and then target them as `self.parents('div.someClass')`

### Fiddle added

[Click to check working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zh4Zx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple "upTo" function to get the first ancestor with a particular `tagName`. If no suitable element is found, it returns `undefined`:

```
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  var el;
  do {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  } while (el.parentNode)
}
```

But if you're using jQuery, no doubt you'd prefer that.